# Mongoimport with SSL

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I want to dump a database in a remote server `www.myweb.io` with ssl. The mongo version is `2.6.12`. It seems that I have to use [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/). I am looking at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myweb.io`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myweb.io www.myweb.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:... ...
```

But I just realized that there is no `/etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.io/fullchain.pem` and `/etc/letsencrypt/live/myweb.io/privkey.pem` in my server. Does anyone know why the website still works?

Then in this case, where should i find `--sslCAFile` or `--sslPEMKeyFile` to make `mongoimport` work?

Comment: Nginx is a web server, so the configuration for this should be unrelated to accessing your MongoDB server. Your MongoDB server may be running on the same host as Nginx, but you probably have to remotely login via `ssh` or similar in order to connect to your MongoDB server. It's not clear why your Nginx server wouldn't be complaining about invalid paths on startup, but that's really a separate question from exporting data from MongoDB.

Comment: The `mongoimport` tool is for importing JSON/CSV data into a MongoDB server; if your goal is to export collection as JSON/CSV you need to use `mongoexport`. If you want to backup a database (rather than a single collection) you should use [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/). With the current information in your question it is unclear what you actually need in order to connect to your MongoDB server, but I would suggest looking at the connecting string used in your application. The same connection options should work for the MongoDB command line tools.